# How to compare between two directories and get the missing files? c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, directory, compare

Thats the code :

```
enter code here 

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] Folder1 = Directory.GetFiles(txtFolder1.Text, comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            string[] Folder1FileNames = new string[Folder1.Length];
            int c = 0;
            string fname1;


            foreach (string f in Folder1)
            {
                fname1 = Path.GetFileName(f);
                Folder1FileNames[c] = fname1;

                c++;
            }



            string fname2;
            string[] Folder2 = Directory.GetFiles(txtFolder2.Text, comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            string[] Folder2FileNames = new string[Folder2.Length];
            int t = 0;
            foreach (string f in Folder2)
            {
                fname2 = Path.GetFileName(f);
                Folder2FileNames[t] = fname2;
                t++;

            }
            int m=0;
            foreach (string f in Folder1FileNames)
            {
                while (f != Folder2FileNames[m] && m < Folder2FileNames.Length)
                {
                    m++;
                    if (m == Folder2FileNames.Length)
                    {
                        Label newlabe = new Label();
                        newlabe.Text = f;
                        if(!listBox1.Items.Contains(newlabe.Text))
                        {
                            listBox1.Items.Add(newlabe.Text);

                        }
                    }
                }
                m = 0;
            }



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            label1.Text = ex.Message;
        }
```

I created two arrays that contains Files From SourceDirectory(Folder1) and CompareDirectory(Folder2)  , then more 2 arrays that contains the files name with out the full ptah (in order to compare between the araays) ,then i have tried to compare between the arrays ,and add the missing file to the list box .
the problem is that when I tried it it gave me the first missing file from the source folder , (e.g source folder contains the next files  : a.txt,b.txt,c.txt,d.txt and compare folder contains:a.txt,b.txt , the result in the list box will be c.txt , and the label will show:"you are out of the array index" )
what should i do ?
thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can go with a bit simpler and tidier solution, something like that should work:

```
var dir1Files = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(txtFolder1.Text, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Select(Path.GetFileName);
var dir2Files = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(txtFolder2.Text, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Select(Path.GetFileName);
var diffs = dir1Files.Except(dir2Files).Distinct().ToArray();   

listBox1.Items.AddRange(diffs);
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys , i succeeded to do it in my way.
thats my old code  :

```
int m=0;
        foreach (string f in Folder1FileNames)
        {
            while (f != Folder2FileNames[m] && m < Folder2FileNames.Length)
            {
                m++;
                if (m == Folder2FileNames.Length)
                {
                    Label newlabe = new Label();
                    newlabe.Text = f;
                    if(!listBox1.Items.Contains(newlabe.Text))
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(newlabe.Text);

                    }
                }
            }
            m = 0;
        }
```

the new one is :`

```
 int m = 0;
            foreach (string f in Folder1FileNames)
            {
                m = 0;
                while (f != Folder2FileNames[m] && m < Folder2FileNames.Length-1)
                {
                    m++;
                    if (m == Folder2FileNames.Length-1)
                    {
                        if (Folder2FileNames[m] != f)
                        {

                            Label newlabe = new Label();
                            newlabe.Text = f;
                            if (!listBox1.Items.Contains(newlabe.Text))
                            {
                                listBox1.Items.Add(newlabe.Text);

                            }
                        }


                    }
                }

            }
```

now its working well,in this way im not out of the array index

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Find the set difference between the two folders.  
    // For this example we only check one way.  
    var queryList1Only = (from file in list1  
                          select file).Except(list2, myFileCompare);  

    Console.WriteLine("The following files are in list1 but not list2:");  
    foreach (var v in queryList1Only)  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine(v.FullName);  
    }
```

[See full example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-compare-the-contents-of-two-folders-linq)