# Comparing files in two Folders using C#

Tags: c#

I want to find which files are in one folder that are not in another folder.

In one folder are .HTML files with names like this:

```
TC_234.html
TC_533.html
TC_761.html
TC_584.html
```

In another folder are .EXP files:

```
TC_312.exp
TC_234.exp 
TC_341.exp
TC_761.exp
```

**Expected results:**

First Folder: TC_533, TC_584
Second Folder: TC_312, TC_341

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare between two directories and get the missing files? c# winform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27858619/how-to-compare-between-two-directories-and-get-the-missing-files-c-sharp-winfor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> CompareFolders(string FolderPathOne, string FolderPathTwo)
{
    var folderOne = Directory.EnumerateFiles(FolderPathOne).Select(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f));
    var folderTwo =  Directory.EnumerateFiles(FolderPathTwo).Select(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f));

    yield return folderOne.Except(folderTwo);
    yield return folderTwo.Except(folderOne);
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var results = CompareFolders("Some/Path/One", "Some/Path/Two");
foreach(var folder in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", folder));
}
```

Comment: I am getting an Error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property "Program.CompareFolder(string,string)"

Cannot access non static method "CompareFolders" in static context.